# Click on Link with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find a link in web page and click on It with javascript code ? 
I also tried document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click();
but i want to replace URL instead of ID

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? It would help understand your problem a bit more.

Comment: If you already know the URL then why do you need to click the link? You can just fetch or navigate to the URL on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i want to replace URL instead of ID

Sounds like [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) may be what you're looking for.  Something like this perhaps:

```
document.querySelector('a[href="your_url_here"]').click();
```

If you have multiple matching elements then you might also take a look at [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and perhaps just invoke `.click()` on the first matching element.

Comment: Thank you very much 
is there a way to make a .js file for only this script  ?

Comment: @mhoseinahmadi: You can certainly put this line of code, or any JavaScript code, in a `.js` file.  Why do you think you wouldn't?  It's not clear what you're implying or asking in that comment.

Comment: I am not familiar with js 
so i wonder if you could tell me that what needed to add at beginning and at the end